# Migrated to jRuby. Getting the following 'ripper' error when running db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

Here's the error:

```
c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:9
2:in `block in materialize': Could not find nokogiri-1.6.0-x86-mingw32 in any of
 the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
definition.rb:114:in `specs'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.
rb:120:in `setup'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Software/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_requir
e.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Software/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_requir
e.rb:36:in `require'
For a better pry experience, please use ansicon: http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon
/
the `ripper' lib is not supported on JRuby
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- ripper
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046:in `load'
C:/Users/n0222072/AptanaWorkspace/dcms/config/application.rb:8:in `(root)'
C:/Users/n0222072/AptanaWorkspace/dcms/Rakefile:5:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046:in `load'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here's the gemfile (bundle install works ok):

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'

gem 'activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter'
gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
gem 'jdbc-mssql-azure'

group :development do
    #gem 'better_errors'
    #gem 'binding_of_caller'
    gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'rack-bug', :require => false
  gem "quiet_assets", ">= 1.0.2"
  gem 'bullet'
 # gem 'metrical'
end

group :test, :development do
  #gem "rspec", "~> 2.0"
  #gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.0"
  gem "cucumber", "~> 1.3.1"
  gem "cucumber-rails", :require => false
  gem "autotest-rails", :require => false
  gem "mocha", :require => false
  gem "capybara", "~> 2.1", :require => false
  gem "launchy"
  gem "database_cleaner", :require => false
  gem 'simplecov', :require => false
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'guard-rails'
  gem "guard-bundler"
  gem "guard-cucumber"
  #gem "guard-rspec"
  # gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0', :platforms => [:mswin, :mingw]
  # wdm comflicts with jruby
  gem 'brakeman', :require => false
  # gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rails_best_practices'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.6'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'

  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby, :require => false

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 2.1.1'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'  
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', "~> 2.3.2.0"
end

group :cloudfoundry do
  gem "cf-autoconfig", :platforms => :ruby
  gem "newrelic_rpm", :platforms => :ruby
end


gem 'builder', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'mime-types', '1.23'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem "rufus-scheduler"

gem 'gon'
gem 'rabl'
#gem 'yajl-ruby'
#yajl-ruby conflicts with jruby

gem "adauth", "~> 1.2.1"
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'kaminari'
gem "formtastic-bootstrap", "= 2.1.3"
gem 'carrierwave'

gem 'highcharts-rails'

# gem 'thin'
gem "rack", "= 1.4.5"
gem 'rack-cas'
gem 'rack-cas-client'

gem "mail_form", "= 1.4.1"

gem 'nifty-generators'

gem "axlsx"
gem 'nokogiri'
```

Has anyone seen this before?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has likely the same cause as the other question you raised :

[How to make jruby look for pure java nokogiri instead of mingw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057905)

Fix your **GEM_HOME** / **GEM_PATH** env and than proceed ...