# How to make jruby look for pure java nokogiri instead of mingw?

Tags: jruby

I just switched to jRuby and I'm able to get my gems installed, but when I try to run rake commands I get the following error.  How can I tell jRuby to use nokogiri-1.6.0-java instead of nokogiri-1.6.0-x86-mingw32?

Error:

```
c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:9
2:in `block in materialize': Could not find nokogiri-1.6.0-x86-mingw32 in any of
 the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
definition.rb:114:in `specs'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler.
rb:120:in `setup'
        from c:/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/bundler-1.3.4/lib/bundler/
setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Software/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_requir
e.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Software/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_requir
e.rb:36:in `require'
For a better pry experience, please use ansicon: http://adoxa.3eeweb.com/ansicon
/
the `ripper' lib is not supported on JRuby
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- ripper
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046:in `load'
C:/Users/n0222072/AptanaWorkspace/dcms/config/application.rb:8:in `(root)'
C:/Users/n0222072/AptanaWorkspace/dcms/Rakefile:5:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046:in `load'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0):

it should have worked - I'm not that much familiar with Ruby-ing on Windows but this is definitely an issue of having both MRI and JRuby on the PATH - most importantly messing with each others **GEM_HOME** / **GEM_PATH** (you might check the paths from irb by running `Gem.path`) - you need to isolate those - make sure they point to the right direction.

when using JRuby stuff such as these should **not** be loaded: 
C:/Software/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb

maybe always using `bundle exec` might help as well although I'm not sure if it validates consequences of having a wrong **GEM_HOME**

that is the reason why the correct nokogiri gem was not seen since it was looking for the wrong one due to custom_require.rb from MRI